# Lock screen command Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: command-line, gnome, 17.10, lock-screen

What is the lock screen command in Ubuntu 17.10?

I want to shortcut the command since I don't have any dedicated special key for this on my Lenovo T470s. If I press the <kbd>super</kbd> (Windows) key and search for 'lock screen' I get a button to click on that does the job but I can't figure out the terminal command from there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can lock screen using the default <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> key combination (<kbd>Super</kbd> is usually the <kbd>Windows</kbd> key).

You can also lock using the following commands

```
gnome-screensaver-command --lock
```

(needs `gnome-screensaver` package installed)

or

```
dbus-send --type=method_call --dest=org.gnome.ScreenSaver /org/gnome/ScreenSaver org.gnome.ScreenSaver.Lock
```

(needs GDM).

Answer (score 1):

The new 19.10 way of doing this is:

> xdg-screensaver lock